# Translate a sentence using "ein Stück"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

The sentence is as follows:

*Es ist die unersättliche Neugier des Menschen, die mit dieser Mission ein Stück weit gestillt werden kann.*

The first part of the sentence I believe translates to: "It is the insatiable curiosity of man..."

But the second half doesn't seem to directly translate easily, I am unsure what the use of ein Stück does to the sentence, as I read that it can sometimes not be directly translate to english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, the word "weit" is necessary for understanding the meaning of the sentence. "Ein Stück weit" is an idiom and means

> bis zu einem gewissen Grade; ziemlich; teilweise.
>   (to a certain extent, partially, somewhat)

The sentence can be translated to:
"It is the insatiable curiosity of man that can be somewhat satisfied with this mission."

Comment: I will noch ergänzen, dass es eine moderne Phrase ist, die sich erst in den letzten Jahren ausgebreitet und viele, elegantere Formulierungen - hoffentlich nur vorrübergehend - ein Stück weit verdrängt hat.

Comment: "Teilweise", "bis zu einem gewissen Grade" legen für mich eine Obergrenze fest, während "ein Stück weit" eine Untergrenze festlegt. Ich glaube, ich würde mich rausreden, indem ich den Satz zu "...mission helps satisfying the insatiable curiosity of man......"  umstellen würde. Ich denke, das ist das, was im Deutschen gemeint ist.